# Finding a largest edgeless subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to solve a following problem:

Given a list of people and their acquaintances, throw a largest party (with the most people) where no two people know each other.

This means I have to find a largest edgeless subgraph of a graph.

More formally (but far from formal), if you have a graph (where the graph could be anything from an edgeless graph to a complete graph), what is the minimal number of nodes you have to delete in order to turn it into an edgeless graph (an which nodes are those)?

If the graph is complete, the solution is simple, delete all but one (any) node.
If the graph is edgeless, it's already solved.

The approach I came up with for all the other cases is as follows:

Create a map where each node maps to a set of all the other nodes it's connected to. Each edge can be represented as A -> B (B is in the set of A) and B -> A (A is in the set of B). In order to resolve such cases, map is sorted by the number of edges and the node that has most edges retains the nodes in its set, but the node itself is removed from the set of any other node. The map should be re-sorted after each such step.

Once that is done, we can remove every node that doesn't have an empty node list, and the remaining nodes make up an edgeless graph. But is it the largest?

It is possible that multiple nodes will have the same number of edges. Lets try to resolve this graph in several ways:

```
1 -> 2, 3, 4
2 -> 1, 4, 5
3 -> 1, 4, 5
4 -> 1, 2, 3
5 -> 2, 3
```

If I resolve 1 first, I get this:

```
2 -> 4, 5
3 -> 4, 5
4 -> 2, 3
5 -> 2, 3

3 -> 4, 5
4 -> 3
5 -> 3

4 ->
5 ->
```

If I resolve 2 first, I get this:

```
3 -> 1, 4, 5
1 -> 3, 4
4 -> 1, 3
5 -> 3

1 -> 4
4 -> 1
5 ->

4 ->
5 ->
```

If I resolve 4 first, I get this:

```
1 -> 2, 3
2 -> 1, 5
3 -> 1, 5
5 -> 2, 3

5 -> 2, 3
2 -> 5
3 -> 5

2 ->
3 ->
```

I get a different solution in the last example, which is fine, this problem will likely have more than one solution as to which nodes to keep.

However, while this example does not illustrate it, I'm worried that the order in which I resolve the nodes that have the same number of edges might influence the number of nodes that remain in the end, not just which ones.

Is my suspicion right? Or does in not matter? Has this problem been solved? Can it be solved in polynomial time? Is there a better approach to this problem? Does it have a name I can search it by?

EDIT: The more I think about it, the more it seems that removing the node with most edges won't always lead to the optimal solution. There might be a situation where I would subsequently remove all the nodes it's connected to, meaning I could have left the node in.

Comment: The (induced) subgraph you're looking for is an [independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)).

Comment: This is the maximum independent set problem, which is known to be NP-complete.  Consequently, any efficient heuristic is doomed to be non-optimal in some cases... unless you're extremely lucky :).

Comment: If either of you can turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.